# .NET Entity Framework - IEnumerable VS. IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, ienumerable, iqueryable

Please see this line of code. This is an invocation of a stored procedure, which returns an `ObjectResult<long?>`. In order to extract the long values I added the Select:

```
dbContext.FindCoursesWithKeywords(keywords).Select(l => l.Value);
```

Based on intellisense this Select returns `IEnumerable<long>`.

I'm not sure whether I read it somewhere or maybe just got used to this assumption - I always thought that when the EF API returns an `IEnumerable` (and not `IQueryable`) then this means that the results have been materialized. Meaning they've been pulled from the database.

I found out today that I was wrong (or maybe that's a bug?). I kept getting the error

> "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads
>   running in the session"

Basically, this error tells you that you're trying to save changes while the db reader is still reading records.

Eventually I solved it by (what I considered a long shot) and added `ToArray()` call to materialize the `IEnumerable<long>`...

So - the bottom line - should I expect `IEnumerable` results from EF to contain results that haven't materialized yet? If yes then is there a way to know whether an `IEnumerable` has been materialized or not?

Thanks and apologies if this is one of those 'duhhh' questions...  :)

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything specifically documented for EF, but for Linq in general, an `IEnumerable<T>` is no more "materialized" than an `IQueryable<T>` - both are generally assumed to use deferred execution.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: However, I think ObjectResult<T> will always execute when the function is called... (in this case FindCoursesWithKeywords)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`IQueryable` is used when you are using Linq-to-entities = you are building declarative LINQ query in your application which will be interpreted by LINQ provider as SQL and executed on the server. Once the query is executed (iterated) it will turn to become IEnumerable and objects will be materialized as needed for iteration = not immediately.

Once you call stored procedure you are not using Linq-to-entities because there is no declarative query built in your application. The query / SQL already exists on database server and you are just invoking it. This will return `IEnumerable` but again it will not materialize all results immediately. Results will be materialized as iterated. This is principle of database cursor / or .NET data reader when you explicitly ask for fetching object.

So if you call something like this:

```
foreach (var keyword in dbContext.FindCoursesWithKeywords(keywords)
                                 .Select(l => l.Value))
{
    ...   
}
```

You are fetching courses one by one (btw. why to load whole course if you are interested only in keywords?). Until you complete or break the loop your data reader is opened to fetch records.

If you instead call this:

```
foreach (var keyword in dbContext.FindCoursesWithKeywords(keywords)
                                 .ToList() // or ToArray 
                                 .Select(l => l.Value))
{
    ...
}
```

You will force query to materialize all results immediately and loop will perform on collection in memory instead of opened database reader.

Difference between `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` is not in the way how data are fetched because `IQueryable` is `IEnumerable`. The difference is in backing construct (something must implement these interfaces).

Comment: Hi, thanks for this explanation! So since this is a stored proc it won't return an IQueryable, as it doesn't support all the features that a query does, right? (btw, I'm fetching courses not keywords)  :)

Answer (score 12):

Working on an `IEnumerable<T>` means that all further operations will happen in C# code, i.e. linq-to-objects. It does not mean that the query has already executed.

Once you degrade to linq-to-objects all data left at this point needs to be fetched from the database and sent to .net. This can degrade performance drastically(For example database indexes won't be used by linq-to-objects), but on the other hand linq-to-objects is more flexible, since it can execute arbitrary C# code instead of being limited by what your linq provider can translate to SQL.

A `IEnumerable<T>` can be both a deferred query or already materialized data. The standard linq operators typically are deferred, and `ToArray()`/`ToList()` are always materialized.

Comment: Thanks for this distinction! So is that something I should be aware of? Are there any implications or gotchas? Cheers!

Comment: The most obvious gotcha is that degenerating to `IEnumerable<T>` can drastically reduce performance. Imagine you degrade at the very beginning of the query, then it's likely that the whole table needs to be fetched instead of filtering using SQL on the server using indexes on the database for speedup. So at the point where you degrade to `IEnumerable<T>` you want to have as little items remaining as possible.

Comment: Not too sure this is correct. Further reading I did + the other answer here say a similar thing - IEnumerable<T> may also not materialize till later when you iterate it. If I understand that right this is because when you exec a stored proc you get a full IQueryable, because this isn't a full queryable object. Makes sense? :)

Comment: As I said the execution of `IEnumerable<T>` may be deferred, but isn't required to be deferred. That depends on the class implementing it. But if you for example execute a `Where` clause on an `IEnumerable<T>` even the elements that don't fulfill the condition need to be sent to C# and tested one by one. But I don't know what a stored procedure returns, since I've never used them.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable will not hydrate until materialized.  If calling a stored procedure I would think that there is no further filter required, I mean you send parameters to a stored procedure to produce the desired subset of data returned.  IEnumerable tied to a stored procedure is fine.  However if you are fetching the entire contents of a table, then filtering in the application you should have a strategy.  Like, do not ToList() the IEnumerable of the table, you will materialize all rows.  Sometimes this will cause an out of memory exception.  Besides why consume memory without reason.  Use IQueryable against the context, that way you can filter the table at the Data Source, and not in the application.  In answer, you have to materialize it.  IEnumerable is an interface, only materializing it will "initialize" its type and produce something in my understanding.

Answer (score -5):

IEnumerable :  LINQ to Object and LINQ to XML.

IQueryable : LINQ to SQL

Comment: IQueryable is a type that has not yet been executed. Basically it is the "query". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.100).ASPX

Virutally has nothing to do with LINQ to SQL, or Linq to Anything. It is an interface to provide access to any sort of data provider.