# Does filtering of data take place in the controller, service or repository layers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, repository

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3`.  I get my view's data in the following sequence:

```
Controller -> Service Layer -> Repository
```

In my repository I have a GetAll method that brings back all the records for a specific object, like Category.

So if I need a list of the all the categories then in my controller I would have something like:

```
IEnumerable<Category> categories = categoryService.GetAll();
```

In the service layer I would have something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetAll()
{
     return categoryRepository.GetAll();
}
```

Now this is what I need to know where do I actually start to filter the data?  Can it be done anywhere in one of these 3 layers or does it only have to be in the repository layer?  Lets say I need all the parent categories.  Do I have the `.GetAll.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == null);` in my controller, service layer, or repository layer?

Do I have it like this in my controller:

```
IEnumerable<Category> categories = categoryService.GetParentCategories();
```

And in my service layer I can have:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetParentCategories()
{
     return categoryRepository.GetAll.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == null);
}
```

Or does my service layer have to look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetParentCategories()
{
     return categoryRepository.GetParentCategories();
}
```

And then in my repository layer like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetParentCategories()
{
     return GetAll()
          .Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == null);
}
```

Please can someone help clarify this confusion that I have.  There might be different scenarios.  I might bring back all categories that have an active status.  I might bring back categories with an inactive status.  Then do I need a method for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should filter at the closest you can from the data source, otherwise you'll be retrieving records to upper layers that will just be discarded due to a filtering option. This does not scale well, so you need to expose filtering capabilities at all layers that require it, but make sure that the actual filtering is performed in lowest layer possible, generally it is performed at the database level.

In the example you posted if use `GetAll` which return an `IEnumerable` of all the records and only then apply the filtering you'll have problems in the future because you're basically loading an entire table into memory and only then applying a filtering.

Since you're using EF you could take advantage of the deferred execution properties of the `IQueryable`. Check:

[.NET Entity Framework - IEnumerable VS. IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606633/net-entity-framework-ienumerable-vs-iqueryable)

[Should a Repository return IEnumerable , IQueryable or List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102149/should-a-repository-return-ienumerablet-iqueryablet-or-listt)

---

**Update:** Following up on your comment you should also check:

[LINQ to entities vs LINQ to objects - Are they the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192040/linq-to-entities-vs-linq-to-objects-are-they-the-same)

Comment: The GetAll whas just a sample method, the main focus is on the filtering part.  Do I then create a method in the repository for each use?  But doesn't the .Where(...) work like a sql select with a where clause?

Comment: Only when you are using LINQ to entities and you'll need an `IQueryable` for that.

Comment: Yes. I have a method Get<T> tat is IQueryable in ther epository, so the repository can handle all conditions one throws at it. A GetALlUsers()method makes me fire people. It is inefficient like hell. Pulling in 100.9000 users to get the one by name - no.

Answer (score 5):

You should always try to fetch as little as possible from the database. And you should therefore do all filtering in your repository classes.

Many articles suggests that you create and use generic repositories.  But imho they will not work very well when your application grows. I recommend that you create proper repository classes with proper search methods like:

```
emailRepository.GetForUser("Ada");
userRepository.GetNewUsers();
```

First of all, you hide implementation details like how to identify new users. It also makes the code easier to understand and extend than using a generic query.

You can also add some filtering options:

```
emailRepository.GetForUser("Ada", Filtering.New().Paged(1, 20).SortedBy("FirstName"));
```

Unlike @JoãoAngelo I do NOT recommend that you use `IQueryable` outside of your repository. By doing so you'll move the database execution to outside your repository class. And that means that any errors can no be handled by your repository.