# How to load value of last employeeid + 1 in add action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have controller name emp have action add

i need when action add view loaded display last value increased by one in

employeeid textbox .

meaning suppose i have in employee table employeeid value 1 then when action add

view loaded employeeid must have 2 .

so that how to do that please ?

in action what i write

[httpget]
Hide   Copy Code
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
what i write here
}
on view add 
what i write here

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmployeeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EmployeeId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

What I have tried:

```
  var results = _context.GetAll().Where(Employee => Employee.EmployeeId> Employee.EmployeeId).OrderBy(Employee => Employee.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
```

**and i pass model to view**

```
<form asp-action="Create">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmployeeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EmployeeId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BranchCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BranchCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BranchCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmployeeName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EmployeeName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmployeeAge" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EmployeeAge" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeAge" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="JoinDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="JoinDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="JoinDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="Active" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need this ? I have a feeling that you should rely on database to generate the next ID value for you. EF will do that.

Comment: can you show me how to do that please

Comment: can you show me how to do that please

Comment: When your entity has a primary key, Is EF not doing that for you when you save a new record ?

Comment: This is not a sensible thing to do, because your database usually takes care of this, during the insert of the record. If you generate the id, when your view loads, then another user does the same and inserts before you, that Id will already exist, when you hit submit, thus most likely raising an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `.GetAll()` , it'll be cause for performance issue. it means you are loading all employee records to the application side, then you are actually querying to loaded employee data. just think about if you have 50K+ employee. So, you have to use LINQ `IQueryable` extension methods, which will generate the SQL operation based on your design query.

**Help Link:**[.NET Entity Framework - IEnumerable VS. IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606633/net-entity-framework-ienumerable-vs-iqueryable)

Please Try This,  if you want to do some other expressions.

```
context.Employee.Select(x => x.EmployeeId).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model have property `EmployeeId` then set this value to it like below.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Employee();
    model.EmployeeId = _context.GetAll().Max(Employee => Employee.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault() + 1;

    return View(model);
}
```

Or if you don't have `Model` to pass to `View` then use `ViewBag`.

```
ViewBag["maxEmployeeId"] = _context.GetAll().Max(Employee => Employee.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault() + 1;
```

Comment: ok good and in view how to pass this value of variable var maxEmployeeId

Comment: You can use `ViewBag` for that.

Comment: one thing remaining if possible on view how to define ViewBag["maxEmployeeId"]

Comment: Are you passing any `model` to your `View`?